# Does a toneless syllable have no f0? How to distinguish a toneless syllable? Please help

Tags: tone, tonal-languages, acoustics

If I put speech data on praat, how will I be able to tell which syllable is toneless in a tonal language since the tbu has a vowel already. And the vowel also has got f0.

Answer (score 3):

Tonelessness has no particular inherent phonetic meaning. It is a phonological term and depends on a phonological analysis.

At a phonetic level, what we have is pitch, shown by F0.

We then perform a phonological analysis to see what pitches (or pitch contours) are meaningfully distinct in the language to produce a set of tones. The phonetic realisation of these tones typically depends on nearby tones (this is called tone sandhi).

A toneless syllable is one which is not assigned any of the tones in our analysis. Its pitch is not just affected by nearby tones, but *entirely* determined by them. As such, to recognise a toneless syllable from a spectrogram you would need to read up on the phonetics of toneless syllables in the language in question, or if you have a sufficiently large sample, attempt a phonological analysis of your own.

As an analogy, consider consonants. Most consonants phonemes have defined place and manner of articulation. These may vary slightly depending on their environment (allophony), but their environment does not completely determine their realisation. Some languages have placeless (or even entirely featureless) consonant phonemes though, such as the /Q/ phoneme of Standard Japanese which has no realisation of its own, but it is realised identically to a following consonant (i.e. it produces gemination).

Toneless syllables are much more common (both cross-linguistically and within individual languages) than placeless or featureless phonemes, but it should hopefully illustrate the point that without already having a phonological analysis of the language they can't be recognised from a spectrogram alone.

Comment: Also, a tonemically toneless syllable may in fact have exactly the same contour as a tone-carrying syllable. For example, a neutral-tone syllable following a second-tone syllable in Mandarin generally has the same tone contour as a canonical first-tone syllable (high level) – it’s just (usually) shorter and less prominent. It can be almost impossible in some cases to distinguish between 2-1 and 2-X, though.

Answer (score 0):

"Toneless" means that the F0 value of a vowel is entirely the result of rules of phonetic implementation, and that the right phonological analysis is one where a certain supposed tonal category, perhaps L tone, actually corresponds to "having no tone feature". Before you set Praat aside in favor of purely phonological analysis, you should know what a common phonetic diagnostic for tonelessness is.

A typical assumption regarding physical realization of tone is that categories like H, M or L refer to a specific pitch target, so that in the sequence H-M-H pitch first rises to the H target, then drops towards the L target, then rises back to the H target. Similar but still different pitch excursions would characterize the sequence H-L-H or L-H-L. Pitch does not jump instantaneously between H and M or L and H, there is a window for implementing the target. In a language where tones are fully specified (Yoruba is a classic example), that window is about a syllable long.

There are some languages – typically ones with just a H vs L distinction – where there is a somewhat asymmetrical distribution of tone types, and where the pitch value of L tone is a function of the pitch of the preceding and following syllables. For example, in a sequence L-L-L-L-H-L, F0 gradually rises over many or all of the syllables which precede the H. The reasoning here is that L does not define a pitch target, and L is literally not there, instead, the pitch interpolation principle (for H) is that one continuously "climbs up" towards pitch target defined by H. Similarly, in the case of H-L-L-L-L, one reaches the F0 target value of H from the start, then pitch slowly declines thereafter, across many syllables which have to pitch target value – the ones that are toneless.

There is a terminological problem in talking about a certain transcriptional entity being "toneless", that tonelessness can be weak or strong, a fact that may be ignored. Strong tonelessness is where there is absolutely no evidence for a phonological specification of some tone like L (therefore pitch on L is purely numeric calculation in the phonetics), and weak tonelessness is where there is evidence for filling in L as a phonological category, but the evidence is limited to late allophonic rules which do not neutralize lexical contrasts. M tone in Yoruba is a classic case of an underspecified tone that is nevertheless filled in as a M tone towards the end of the phonology – M in Yoruba is *mostly* inert in phonology, not *entirely* inert.

An interesting but separate question is, what kinds of evidence is used in phonology to support a claim of underspecification, i.e. the claim that a certain lacks any specification for a certain phonological property, such as "H-ness" or "voicing".